# What Windows Vista/7 program for scaling windows like compiz?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

There's this game I'm playing which uses raster graphics, but it is not suited for high resolution because the text is too small. In GNOME I would have been able to use Compiz scale effect to solve that, albeit being blurry. Seeing Windows Vista and 7 (excluding Basic editions) come with DWM, I suppose it should be possible to utilize it to scale any window up. In fact, that's what I see when I run non-DPI-aware application on desktop set to high DPI.

There's something called [DWM Scaler Power Toy](http://www.hardwaregeeks.com/board/showthread.php?t=23567) but I have no idea what it does, since I never manage to download it without errors.

P/S: Alternatives to avoid:-

- Changing resolution: most LCD monitors don't look good on non-native resolution
- Playing on VM: Startup time prolonged
- Dual-boot: Well, I've heard of people rebooting from Linux to Windows to play games, but the other way around? You've gotta be kidding me!

Answer (score 2):

I have found one utility which seems to work quite well, it is called [WindowWatcher](http://www.airesoft.co.uk/windowwatcher). It creates a cloned window with a zoomed image, the window  can be resized and repositioned as needed.

It requires a DWM driver (Vista, Windows 7 or newer).

The utility is free to download (not open source).

I am using it in tandem with [Borderless-Gaming](https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming) open source utility, which I use to make the zoomed window to cover whole screen with borders removed. With those two together the resulting experience is much like running full screen.